# Не получается записать _PartialView в <div>

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

Пытаюсь организовать работу с закладками (tab):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Schools.cshtml**

```
...
<div>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li id="tab_info"><a href="#">Реквизиты</a></li>
        <li id="tab_rmschool"><a href="#">Отчеты</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#School').change(function () {
            var schoolid = $("#ddlSchool").val();                
            $.ajax({                    
                url: "/Report/GetRMschoolPV?_schoolID=" + schoolid,
                type: "GET",
                data: "@User.Identity.Name",//если в Razor
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#tab_rmschool").html(data)
                   }
                 })
        });
    });
</script>
```

Но после изменений в `School` вот что происходит:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`url: "/Report/GetRMschoolPV?_schoolID=" + schoolid` возвращает `частичное представление`.

В итоге, как видно на скрине: частичное представление то загружено в блок `tab_rmschool`. Но этот самый блок мне еще перекрыл вкладку с ее наименованием "Отчеты".

1. Что я не так делаю?
2. Может есть какой-то шаблон? Ведь как мне кажется таким функционалом
   пользуются часто.

Comment: а в чем проблема то? вставляется не туда?

Comment: @Buka вставляется туда, но это вставка перекрывает мне наименование этой вкладки - `Отчеты`.

Comment: а почему бы Вам не создать блок в который Вы будете вставлять результат запроса(`<div id="tabContent"></div>`) который будет располагаться ниже вкладок

Comment: Это называется "что просили, то и получили". Найдите другой блок, который вы будете "перекрывать", если отчеты не нравятся...

Comment: @PavelMayorov да действительно). Спасибо @Buka! Также хочется отметить, что отвечая на свой 2 вопрос у `jQuery UI` оказался удобный виджет `Tabs` для этих целей.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто создайте другой `div` под теми которые вы не хотите "скрыть" и загрузите свой код в этот `div`.